# Opening HTML file as text on Android

Tags: android, html, ios, react-native

The problem is:
Text from HTML file not showing on Android but showing on iOS

I have notice that there is something not showing on my page when I access it on Android devices but showing on iOS Devices. I mean that on iOS Devices only shows the text that needs to be seen by the user, but on Android it shows the whole HTML file (also including the tags).

Maybe in the HTML File is the problem.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
<p style="margin-bottom: 14pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 14pt;"><span style="font-family: Verdana;">The APP</span></p>
<p style="margin-top: 14pt; margin-bottom: 14pt; line-height: normal; font-size: 14pt;"><span style="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold;">Date: 12.03.2022</span></p>
```

Comment: Could it be the Font-family? I know that apple ignores some of the font styles.

Comment: No, it's not the font-family